# Automatic upload GPS location

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gps

Normally I prefer to lurk the forums for answers but I can't find one so here goes...

I have a custom fleet management system that i wrote in ASP for a client and they have requested GPS functionality so that they can get rid of their monthly satellite service. I purchased a serial GPS dongle for the laptops in the cab of the trucks and wrote a short Windows service for the trucker's laptops to read and translate the data. Currently, I overwrite a text file every 10 seconds with the translated location. (The reason for doing this is Google API apparently does not recognize external location sensors in Windows 7.)

Now, however, I need to get that info to the server so that the dispatcher can be updated with the locations, and so that the truck drivers and tag their locations at customers for other drivers who may have to cover their route. I figure I would have to use JavaScript, but was hoping someone could send me in the right direction. I have tried to prepopulate a value into an html file upload widget but obviously that does not work

Or can i save the file in temporary internet files and grab it via ASP? Would it be better to use sockets to push to the server? I would like to incorporate the site I already have written...

I DON'T NEED ANY CODE, I just need to get pointed in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: Which language do you use to create the text file? Maybe, instead of creating that file, you can directly push the data to your server, through a REST web-service.

Comment: I'm using VB but i could easily rewrite it in C#. The problem then becomes how do i identify which machine sent the location, and how does that correspond to the user logged into the web app, as I don't think I can read, say, a MAC address over the internet. I'll look into REST though.

Comment: Actually dmarucco I'm doing it slightly different using xml, but your suggestion is what prompted the idea. I'll post my solution after I get off work. Thanks!

Comment: How do you solved the identification problem? It it an intresting argument. Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it. Credit to dmarruco for suggesting REST, it inspired me to use a similar solution with xml. Client side is as follows:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Net


Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myport As SerialPort = New SerialPort("COM3", "4800", Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One)
    Dim availableSerialPorts As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String) = My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
    If availableSerialPorts.Contains("COM3") Then
        Dim dstring As String = ""
        Try
            If myport.IsOpen Then
                myport.Close()
            End If
            myport.Open()
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
            Dim datastring As String = myport.ReadExisting
            dstring += datastring
            myport.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            If myport IsNot Nothing Then
                myport.Close()
            End If
        End Try

        Dim loc As Integer
        Dim search As String = "$GPGGA"
        loc = InStr(1, dstring, search, CompareMethod.Text)

        Dim latstart As Integer = loc + 18
        Dim lonstart As Integer = loc + 30
        Dim lat As String = Mid(dstring, latstart, 9)
        Dim lon As String = Mid(dstring, lonstart, 10)
        Dim gpgga As String = Mid(dstring, loc, 50)

        If Left(lat, 1) <> "," And Left(lon, 1) <> "?" Then

            Dim HH As String = Left(lat, 2)
            Dim mmmm As String = Mid(lat, 3, 7)
            Dim mconv As String = Val(mmmm) / 60
            mconv = mconv.Replace("0.", "")
            Dim latcoord As String = HH & "." & mconv
            Dim lH As String = Left(lon, 3)
            Dim lmm As String = Mid(lon, 4, 7)
            Dim lmC As String = Val(lmm) / 60
            lmC = lmC.Replace("0.", "")
            Dim loncoord As String = "-" & lH & "." & lmC
            Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
            Dim xmldec = xmldoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ASCII", "")
            Dim outx As XmlElement
            outx = xmldoc.CreateElement("Location")
            xmldoc.AppendChild(outx)
            Dim root As XmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement
            xmldoc.InsertBefore(xmldec, root)
            Dim xmlat As XmlElement
            xmlat = xmldoc.CreateElement("lat")
            xmlat.InnerText = latcoord
            outx.AppendChild(xmlat)

            Dim xmlon As XmlElement
            xmlon = xmldoc.CreateElement("lon")
            xmlon.InnerText = loncoord
            outx.AppendChild(xmlon)
            Dim machineid As String = "1" 'arbitrary for testing purposes
            Dim xmach As XmlElement
            xmach = xmldoc.CreateElement("MID")
            xmach.InnerText = machineid
            outx.AppendChild(xmach)

            Dim url As String = "http://fakeurl.com/getxml.aspx" 'the receiving page goes here
            Dim wreq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim bytestowrite As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(xmldoc.ToString)
            wreq.Method = "POST"
            wreq.ContentLength = bytestowrite.Length
            wreq.ContentType = "text/xml"
            Dim mystream As Stream = wreq.GetRequestStream()
            mystream.Write(bytestowrite, 0, bytestowrite.Length)
            mystream.Close()

        Else
            MsgBox("No Fix")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Disconnected")
    End If
End Sub

End Module
```

Forgive the try/catch this is the test code before i published it.